# closing a window popup based on result

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I am trying to open a window from a click then after the response in the url that consist of a confirmation page if is success it will close the window.

I opened my window with this:

```
        url = 'http:/mywebsite/index';
        width = 545;
        height = 433;
        var leftPosition, topPosition;
        //Allow for borders.
        leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
        //Allow for title and status bars.
        topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
        //Open the window.
        window.open(url, "Window2", "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
```

The returned of the URL `http:/mywebsite/index` is a json dump with a dictionary of success whether true or false. I code this with python btw.

The problem I am encountering is how to close the window from the return of the python.

I tried returning a string as HTML and javascript consisting of `window.close()`. But no luck. Please do tell me if I am doing something wrong or what should be the method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the object returned by window.open and call close() on that object:

var mywindow;

mywindow = window.open(...);

...

mywindow.close();